# Thread-safe singleton and nonatomic properties issue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios5, singleton, atomic

I have an issue, described below and solution. But I think our solution is not really "right way" to solve this issue.

## 1: I have thread safe singleton for Data

```
//DataSingleton.h
@interface DataSingleton : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *userLogin;
-(void)setPrettyLogin:(NSString*)prettyLogin;
@end
```

and

```
//DataSingleton.m
#import "DataSingleton.h"

@synthesize userLogin   = _userLogin;

+(id)sharedSingleton{

    static dispatch_once_t DataSPred;
    static DataSingleton *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&DataSPred, ^{ shared = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return shared;
}

-(void)setPrettyLogin:(NSString*)prettyLogin{
    _userLogin = prettyLogin;
}

@end
```

## 2: Also I have same singleton for Network and i use feature

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
         { <block> }];
// I know about mainQueue - only for UI. Here it is, for clarity.
```

## 3: The issue

When i try get **[[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] userLogin]** within NSURLConnection block (in one of NetworkSingleton methods) - i get same time  and in **_userLogin** i found some garbage =(

## 4:Bad solution

I spend about an hour and don't find correct answer for my question. And create this:

```
//DataSingleton.h
@interface DataSingleton : NSObject{
    NSString* _userLogin;
}

-(NSString*)userLogin;
-(void)setPrettyLogin:(NSString*)prettyLogin;
@end
```

and

```
//DataSingleton.m
#import "DataSingleton.h"

+(id)sharedSingleton{

    static dispatch_once_t DataSPred;
    static DataSingleton *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&DataSPred, ^{ shared = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return shared;
}

-(NSString*)userLogin{
    return _userLogin;
}

-(void)setPrettyLogin:(NSString*)prettyLogin{

    _userLogin = [prettyLogin retain];
    //I can,t release it and 
    //static code analysis is not happy with what is happening
}

@end
```

Are any one have the idea?

Best regards
Sergey

Comment: Well, your singleton `isn't` thread safe. Your initialization is, but not your methods that actually do something.

Comment: Read this to get a clue ... http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/13/objectivce-c-atomic-properties-threading-andor-custom-settergetter/

Comment: To @RobertVojta - Yes, I see now that "Atomic does not mean thread safe", but what I must do that the userLogin have equal value for any thread?

Comment: Please no holly-war about thread-safe singleton implementation ))

Comment: @WINSergey to make it shorter, you can also read http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html See **Update:** section at the end of this article, especially point 3, which is about `volatile` and `@synchronized` to be sure that all CPUs/cores see same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retain the value in the setter. Actually the problem has nothing to do with threading.

Your function is almost correct.

```
-(void)setPrettyLogin:(NSString*)prettyLogin {
    _userLogin = [prettyLogin retain];
}
```

But it should be

```
-(void)setPrettyLogin:(NSString*)prettyLogin {
    if (_userLogin != prettyLogin) {
         NSString *tmp = _userLogin;
         _userLogin = [prettyLogin retain];
         [tmp release];
    } 
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [_userLogin release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now if you wan't to release the value call

```
[[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] setPrettyLogin:nil];
```

Comment: Yes, thanks )) But I no want to write write getter/setter methods for any @properties.
I want write 

    @propertie(super-thread-safe-atomized) NSString* userLogin;

and

    @ syntesize userLogin=_userLogin =)